# How to change hint size in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a `hintText` in a `TextField`, I can change its color but cannot change its size.

How can I change it?

It's a sample of code from the [documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/text-input):

```
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    border: InputBorder.none,
    hintText: 'Enter a search term'
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    border: InputBorder.none,
    hintText: 'Enter a search term',
    hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 20), // you need this
  ),
)
```